# Mounting a directory?

Tags: linux, busybox

I want to mount a particular folder as /system. 
I tried `mount -t ext2 -o loop /sd-ext/rom/system /system`
I get `mount: mounting /sd-ext/rom/system /system failed: Block device required`
Im using android, so im limited to android shell and busybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Android, but if you want to mount a *directory* instead of a *device* you have to use mount with the `--bind` option.

If it's really a file then maybe your Android has no loop device support. Do you have any `/dev/loop*` devices?